# NGXS/Store Action naming reuseability

Tags: ngxs

In the official [documentation](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/actions#how-should-you-name-your-actions), it is suggested that we put inside the brackets `[]` where the Action comes from:

> Names should contain three parts:
>
> A context as to where the command came from, [User API], [Product
>   Page], [Dashboard Page].
>
> A verb describing what we want to do with the entity.
>
> The entity we are acting upon, User, Card, Project.
>
> Examples:
>
> [User API] GetUser
>
> [Product Page] AddItemToCart
>
> [Dashboard Page] ArchiveProject

However, what if there's 2 different locations where we're calling the Action?

In my Angular app, I have the following Action:

```
export class ClearActiveItem {
  static readonly type = '[Items Page] ClearActiveItem';
}
```

How do I name this so I emphasize that `ClearActiveItem` can be dispatched from another place other than `Items Page`?

Comment: I don't find it helpful to prefix [where action comes from] so I did not follow this suggestion. Instead, my actions are placed within a TypeScript namespace for the respective state container. And I prefix it with the namespace's name. Useful when you have lots of @State() containers. A simple example - https://github.com/kctang/reactive-with-ngxs/blob/master/src/demo3/Library.state.ts

Answer (score 2):

Actions should capture events, not commands.

Therefore you should create two actions, one for each location where the event happens.

A great video on the topic is [Good Action Hygiene by Mike Ryan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmnsEvoy-gY) It's for NgRx, but the same concepts apply to NGXS.